# AngularJS - Best way to share resolve dependency data with nested controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I have an existing AngularJS route with data from an API that is injected into the page controller (`PrimaryController`) using a route resolve (`myDependency`) from `ngRoute`. I'm adding more functionality to this page that I'm encapsulating in a sub-controller with `ng-controller="SubController as subController"`

That `SubController` operates primarily on `myDependency`, and the `PrimaryController` also operates on it. I can think of three ways to pass the data to `SubController`, and I was wondering if there is a best practice for this.

1. Put the object on `$scope` and access it in the nested controller as `$scope.myDependency`. I'm hesitant to do this because I associate `$scope` properties with data or methods that are used in the HTML, and this object isn't. But this also seems like the most typical way to access data from a parent controller. I could use `controller as` syntax to make the dependency between `SubController` and `PrimaryController` clearer, like `$scope.primary.myDependency`.
2. Put the data in a shared 3rd party service like `MyService.myDependency`. I don't like this very much because this is the only scenario/route in which this service will be used in this way, and it seems like overkill.
3. Access the data using `$route.current.locals.myDependency`. I like this because it makes it clear that `SubController` depends on data from the route. This controller will never be used outside of this context, so I'm not worried about this being too limiting.

I know `ui-router` has support for accessing resolve data in nested views, but we're using `ngRoute`.

Comment: sorry, I did not read it. If you not are using angular-ui router, then it's ok using `ng-controller as controller` syntax.

Comment: thanks for your 3rd suggestion. I did not know it and think it is the cleanest,